# Why are the special characters being ignored in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file and during the startup it says it couldn't find the file it should start.

```
 producer:
  build: docker\producer\ .
  restart: always
  container_name: producer
  command: bash -c "python producers\orch_core.py"
```

The file orch_core.py lies within the folder producers. All I get as an error is:

```
python: can't open file 'producersorch_core.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It seems that the backslash is ignored? Escaping didn't help.

Comment: Why do you have `bash -c` there?  You have two levels of shell (and therefore backslash-escaping) just to run a simple command.  Also, if it's a Linux container, you need a front-slash anyways.

Comment: I have to admit that I am quite unexperienced with these things. This code snippet was just a modified copy. It is a linux container.

Comment: In your Dockerfile, add the line `CMD ["python", "producers/orch_core.py"]` (with a forward slash).  Delete `command:` from the `docker-compose.yml`.  `container_name:` doesn't have a useful effect and you can delete that too.

Comment: @DavidMaze is right - if you are using a linux based image you should use the forward slash instead of backslash for paths (I am guessing you are coming from Win background?) And I would suggest making python the entrypoint using `ENTRYPOINT python` in your Dockerfile and the the command can be only the paht to the .py file as docker will in essence just call ENTRYPOINT + CMD (a simplified example of course)

Comment: I disagree with @KārlisĀbele on this: if `docker run --rm -it imagename /bin/sh` gets paired with a Python entrypoint, you’ll get some rather unexpected behavior.

Comment: @DavidMaze you can always overwrite the entrypoint in your run command... 
It's just that from what I know it's good practice to define the executable/command used as the entrypoint (for some images  I've seen custom entrypoint files, that check for specific CMD and if they don't meet the requirements they simply execute the CMD as a separate command)

Comment: @DavidMaze just wanted to clarify - in Docker documentation they do provide the example of using CMD in format of `["command", "param", "param"]`, and with ENTRYPOINT the same way `["command", "param", "param"]` and it is totally up to each developer how they use it and it also depends on the purpose of the image it self, but in quite a few cases I've noticed that running `docker run -it --rm python test.py` seems quite nice as it is self-explanatory what's going on. So I usually try to stick with the same approach (as long as it makes sense of course)